# Angular ng-repeat for a select, setting one option as selected using $rootScope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following select:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        onchange="User_Changed_Language()" 
        id="HeaderLanguageSelection" 
        style="cursor:pointer;width:100%;height:30px;margin:0;padding:0" 
        title="{{Labels.Change_Language_Tooltip}}">
    <option ng-repeat="One_Language in Languages_List" 
            value="{{One_Language.Code}}" 
            ng-selected="One_Language.Code == current_Language">
        {{One_Language.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Now, `current_Language` is a `$rootScope` variable with a value (e.g. "EN"). I want the select element to display the selected value instead of the very first. What am I doing wrong?

One more note: I know that I could use `ng-click`, but I don't think this is the source of the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `ng-options` and `ng-model` to create options. When model value is set in controller will already be selected at run time. Since `$scope` inherits from `$rootScope` it should work fine as soon as you change the markup

Comment: ng-selected="One_Language.Code == current_Language.Code". Just checking.

Comment: I just checked the doc of ngoptions and it is not clear how do I set the condition for having one of the entries SELECED based on the value of `current_Language`.

Comment: @rbaghbanli, nope. `current_Language` is just text, e.g. "EN".

Comment: Replace from `One_Language.Code == current_Language` to `One_Language.Code == $root.current_Language`. Of Course you need to add dependency in the controller `$rootScope`.

Comment: I tried even though (as far as I know) you don't normally include "$scope" or "$rootScope" within your HTML. In any case, it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

  $scope.Labels = {Change_Language_Tooltip: "change lang"};
  $scope.Languages_List = [
    { name: 'English', Code: 'en' },
    { name: 'Espanol', Code: 'es' },
    { name: 'Italian', Code: 'it' }];
  $rootScope.current_Language = $scope.Languages_List[1];

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>selected item is : {{current_Language}}</p>

  <select class="form-control" 
  onchange="User_Changed_Language()" 
  id="HeaderLanguageSelection" 
  style="cursor:pointer;width:100%;height:30px;margin:0;padding:0" 
  title="{{Labels.Change_Language_Tooltip}}" 
  ng-options="item.name for item in Languages_List track by item.Code"
  ng-model="current_Language">
  </select>

</body>

</html>
```

PS: the selected item (default or initial) must be one element of the items used in the ngOptions list

Comment: Nice!!!!! Thanks for the solution. One comment/question: Should I assume that, if we wish to have two fields shown in the list (e.g. English name + Native name, like `Spanish (Español)` we could just write `ng-options="item.name (item.Native) for item in Languages_List track by item.Code"`?

Comment: you should write `ng-options="item.name + ' ('+item.native+')' for item in Languages_List track by item.code"` (check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). The 'label' part of 'comprehension_expression' is an Angular expression.

Comment: OK. Thanks. It is not always clear how to embed data within Angular's directives/mechanisms.

Comment: unless I did a mistake (checked and rechecked), it does not work for me. Could it be because in your example `current_Language` is an object much the same as any entry in the list while in my case, `current_Language="EN"`?

Comment: The model MUST be one of the elements in the array used as list in the ngOptions directive. So `current_Language` must be equal to `Languages_list[x]`

Comment: OK. Will create a small object with the same structure as `Languages_List[x]` and use it in the above ng-options. Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Hello @beaver. Just wanted to let you know that I made the change you suggested and now it indeed works perfectly. Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad for your success. You might vote up my answer ;)