# Select control option not changing when I set ng-model initially in Ionic App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a select control in my ionic - cordova app. Each option in select control has value and text which is loading with ng-repeat. When I set the ng-model initially the selection not changing. Please help me how to fix this.
Below is the code I used;

```
<select  ng-model="myselecteditem">
 <option ng-repeat="item in myitemlist" value=" {{item.value}}" >{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Below is the code in controllers.js

```
var item = {};
item.value = "";
item.text = "--SELECT--";
$scope.myitemlist.push(item);

item = {};
item.value = "1";
item.text = "item 1";
$scope.myitemlist.push(item);


item = {};
item.value = "2";
item.text = "item 2";
$scope.myitemlist.push(item);

$scope.myselecteditem=$scope.myitemlist[2].value;
```

From the above code the selected item by default will be 'item2' But its '--SELECT--'. Not changing.

Comment: The selected item (default or initial) must be one element of the items used in the ngOptions list, not only the value; check the example on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977375/angular-ng-repeat-for-a-select-setting-one-option-as-selected-using-rootscope/34979002?noredirect=1#comment57703154_34979002

Comment: Thank you beaver. But I already tried this solution. Not working.

Comment: Check the snippet on my edited answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected item (default or initial) must be one element of the items used in the ngOptions list, not only the value.

So you have to write:

```
$scope.myselecteditem=$scope.myitemlist[2];
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myitemlist = [];

  var item = {};
  item.value = "";
  item.text = "--SELECT--";
  $scope.myitemlist.push(item);

  item = {};
  item.value = "1";
  item.text = "item 1";
  $scope.myitemlist.push(item);

  item = {};
  item.value = "2";
  item.text = "item 2";
  $scope.myitemlist.push(item);

  $scope.myselecteditem = $scope.myitemlist[2];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title>Ionic Template</title>
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Select</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content padding="true">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-input item-select">
        <div class="input-label">
          Test
        </div>
        <select ng-model="myselecteditem" ng-options="item.text for item in myitemlist track by item.value">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</body>

</html>
```